# Amount of products added to cart

Tags: php, magento, checkout, product, cart

I am trying to set a item price based on other products added to the cart,

e.g. if there are 4 products 'table'(quantity 4) then product X should be +50€.

First of all i am checking if the `product->getAttributeText('try')` is not false.

In the second step i would like to see how many products are placed from this kind(table).

what i did was:

```
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productQnty = $item->getProduct()->getQty();
}
```

But this is always null.

Comment: I've formatted the question a bit. Please improve the question a bit more, so that a member of the community is able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a "Shopping Cart Price Rule".
Under Conditions, you can set it to only work if there are X number of products in the cart. If you need, you can also specify the rule to only work for a specific product.

Comment: Tha's not what i am looking for i solved it by removing ->getProduct() in foreach.